# Send Variable from Python to PHP

Tags: python, php

I need to send request to my API in PHP with ID of ORDER

Something Like :

http://localhost/api2.php?ID=15

And when i get this PHP:

```
$idOrder= $_GET["ID"];
$smartweb->getOrder($idOrder)
```

Its return Object:

```
object(stdClass)#4 (6) { ["Id"]=> int(15) ["Customer"]=> object(stdClass)#61056 (31) { ["Id"]=> int(15) ["OrderId"]=> int(15) ["Firstname"]=> string(11) "Adam" ["Lastname"]=> string(10) "Nowak" ["Company"]=> string(0) "" ["B2B"]=> bool(false) ["Cvr"]=> string(0) "" ["Ean"]=> string(0) "" ["Address"]=> string(16) test 116" ["Address2"]=> string(0) "" ["Zip"]=> string(4) "3039" ["City"]=> string(7) "Narnia" ["Country"]=> string(2) "DK" ["CountryCode"]=> string(0) "" ["State"]=> string(0) "" ["Phone"]=> string(11) "" ["Mobile"]=> string(0) "" ["Email"]=> string(19) "MAX81OSLO@gmail.com" ["ShippingFirstname"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingLastname"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingCompany"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingAddress"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingAddress2"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingZip"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingCity"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingCountry"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingCountryCode"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingState"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingPhone"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingMobile"]=> string(0) "" ["ShippingEmail"]=> string(0) "" } ["Status"]=> string(1) "1" ["Vat"]=> float(0.25) ["OrderLines"]=> object(stdClass)#61057 (1) { ["item"]=> object(stdClass)#61058 (10) { ["ProductId"]=> int(13372) ["Amount"]=> int(1) ["PacketLines"]=> object(stdClass)#61059 (0) { } ["ProductTitle"]=> string(5) "Testy" ["Discount"]=> float(0) ["Price"]=> float(8) ["PriceRounded"]=> float(8) ["BuyPrice"]=> float(0) ["LineAddresses"]=> object(stdClass)#61060 (0) { } ["VatRate"]=> float(0.25) } } ["Delivery"]=> object(stdClass)#61061 (9) { ["Id"]=> int(15) ["OrderId"]=> int(15) ["DeliveryMethodId"]=> int(2) ["Vat"]=> bool(true) ["Title"]=> string(5) "Fragt" ["Price"]=> float(55.2) ["BuyPrice"]=> float(0) ["ServiceType"]=> string(5) "fedex" ["DroppointId"]=> int(0) } }
```

And now i need to send it back to python and convert it to a Python Object

I try

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request(url='http://localhost/api2.php?ID=15" )
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print (f)
```

But i have Python 3.6 and it does not work.

Can you help me, how can I do this integration?

Edit: i Try this:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost/api2.php?ID=15') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

But it show all document in string

> '\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n  API SmartWeb\r\ ....

Anyway My function in PHP its:

```
function getOrder($id){
    $this->Client->Order_SetOrderLineFields(array('Fields' => 'Amount,Discount,ProductTitle,ProductId,Amount,Price,PriceRounded,BuyPrice,Vat,VatRate'));
    $this->Client->Order_SetFields(array('Fields' => 'Id,Customer,OrderLines,Delivery,Vat,Status'));
    $Order = $this->Client->Order_GetById(array('OrderId' => $id));
    $orderResult = $Order->Order_GetByIdResult;
       var_dump($orderResult);

    return $orderResult;
}
```

So i Print it with dump to know its work.

How i can get it to Python object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong module in the first example and in the second one you used it wrong.

You forgot to add .read() at the end of the request to say that you mean the data that is given back from the server

example(python):

```
import urllib.request

link = "http://localhost/api2.php?ID=15" #Api url with get data here

url = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read() #Retrieves and stores the requested json

result = json.loads(url) #Converts the raw json into a python array usable for python

order = result["order"] #to pull data from the array use something like this
```

Also, to make this work, you'll need to output json with your php api so python can later read it, to do this you'll need to do something like this(php):

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json'); // setting the correct header so your request knows there is json coming

$myObj->order = $orderResult; // prepares the variable for json encoding

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj); // generates the json

print_r($myJSON); // prints the raw generated json

?>
```

I hope this helped you out.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Maybe orderResult ts not clean?

Comment: I Just shoud remove html code from php file....

Its work now :)

Comment: Ah yes, i didn't knew there was html code in your php file too xD